# Meta header broken half the time

Tags: bug, status-norepro

My iot meta header is buggy and not showing reputation correctly

[image]

Half the time:

[image]

Main site with updated reputation:

[image]

Comment: Is it just randomly switching while you browse? What happens if you do a hard page refresh?

Comment: @AdamLear yes it did. I think it always reset to 101 on the questions page. Currently I cannot reproduce it. I'll keep on the lookout.

Comment: Meta rep is always a little delayed from the main site's reputation. It doesn't update immediately but does it on a scheduled basis

Comment: @ZachSaucier Yeah, but it shouldn't be switching back and forth.

Comment: @Helmar I'm going to assume the cause here was similar to [this issue](http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/38/critic-badge-not-activated) and mark this as unreproducible for now. Let me know if it happens again, though.

Comment: @AdamLear I will. Thanks.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com